# In MySQL, how can I get an aggregate function to return 0 after a where clause and a group by?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have a table of users and a table of time-entries. I am trying to obtain the `sum(time_entry.hours_worked)` per employee where the date is within a range of values.

With:

```
SELECT employee.id, COALESCE(SUM(time_entry.hours_worked),0) as `sum`
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN time_entry 
ON employee.id = time_entry.student_id
GROUP BY employee.id;
```

I am able to obtain entries for all employees, even if no hours are worked :

```
+----+--------+
| id | sum    |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 191.00 |
|  2 |  48.00 |
|  3 |   0.00 |
+----+--------+
```

With a where statement:

```
SELECT employee.id, COALESCE(SUM(time_entry.hours_worked),0) AS `sum`
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN time_entry 
ON employee.id = time_entry.student_id
WHERE time_entry.date < 1367798400
GROUP BY employee.id;
```

I obtain an empty set. How can I use the `WHERE` statement and still obtain 0 per employee when no entries are found in the database?

Comment: How's your empty set looks...can you provide an example like the first result set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the condition is on the second table in the `left outer join`.  When there is no match, all the columns are set to `NULL`.  So, the `where` clause fails.  In fact, such a condition is turning the `left outer join` back into an `inner join`.

To fix this, move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT employee.id, COALESCE(SUM(time_entry.hours_worked),0) AS `sum`
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN time_entry 
ON employee.id = time_entry.student_id and
   time_entry.date < 1367798400
GROUP BY employee.id;
```